# java memcopy DirectBuffer

Tags: java, memcpy, bytebuffer

Hi I am working with direct buffers in Java, and I need to have a fast memcopy on them. In C there is the memcpy command, and on Java Arrays I have Arrays.copyOf. But there is no way of using Arrays instead of direct buffers, because I need to transfer those to OpenGL.

Comment: Do you mean, you have a direct ByteBuffer and you need a (fast) copy of that buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "direct" ByteBuffers, there's a [put](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) method which accepts other `ByteBuffer` instances so you can copy around.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `put()` with either a byte[] or a ByteBuffer, this will use a native call memcpy under neither in the Sun/Oracle JDK.

For direct and heap byte buffers `put()` uses the `Bits.copyFromArray()` and `Unsafe.copyMemory()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

check [System.arrayCopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) it's the fastest way to copy part of an array in java